# Getter 'propertyName' took 1174ms to type-check

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-warnings

What's wrong with this computed property? Why compiler is taking so long to compile it?. Any work around to fix this?

[image]

I tried to calculate the size of a frame through a computed property but it takes so long to compile

Comment: Post code as text and not an image.

Comment: Try `return CGSize(width: view.frame.width / Double(viewControllers.count) * 0.95, height: 50.0)`.

Comment: Convert count to CGFloat. So all computation are made in CGFloat which is the default for CGSize and other CoreGraphics floating var

Comment: @PtitXav `CGFloat` is `Double` and `Double` is used in [`CGSize` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/cgsize)

Comment: @meaning-matters : CGFloat and Double are equivalent, not the same. There is now (Swift 5.5) an implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

It is a complex calculation. Your statement includes lots of computation(multiplication and division) and type conversion. You should separate conversions and castings.